# How to generate a PWM signal with Visual Basic?

Tags: networking, wireless, pwm, signal

Please help me to get PWM signal (three LEDs) from raspberry pi by using Visual Basic.

I have a problem to generate pulse signal from raspberry pi wirelessly. What I want to do is using a program to track the location or the coordinates of the Micromouse which is mounted with raspberry pi.

Is there somebody can help me? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: it's very unlikely you'll manage to get VB running on Raspberry Pi. please, try Python instead. there are plenty of libraries, including GPIO manipulation and PWM output.

Comment: @lenik Thank you! I will try python, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Visual Studio .NET 2.0 or 3.5+(4.0,4.5) with the [MONO Cross Platform .NET framework](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page). You can use VB code style in Visual Studio, but the recommended programming style is Object Orientated C#, but using VB you can build linear classes "modules" with little drawbacks.

You can [install MONO on the Pi](http://www.raspberry-sharp.org/) and fully supports .NET 2.0, .NET 3.5 with some features missing in .NET 4.5

- Look around on the Mono website for tutorial and search for Mono
  GPIO. There are allot of examples how to use GPIO, Timers, etc in
  MONO.

But if you really insists on using Visual Basic... you are luck, [Mono version 1.2.3 fully supports compiling Visual Basic code](http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support) to IL on the Pi.

*I have made a few application using Visual Basic .NET 4 Console application that do almost anything you want it to do- The longest part is installing MONO and then you can just execute **EXE**'s compiled with the MONO compiler :)*

[Ohh look, free Visual Studio 2013! Thanks new Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40787)

Comment: What I want is actually using a PC with Visual Basic to get PWM signal wirelessly from Raspberry pi. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Although development was discontinued by its owners years ago, Visual Basic is still a closed source, proprietary product.  This means that in order for it to be used on the pi, Microsoft would have to compile and distribute a version for that.  Since they've already discontinued the product, the chances of this are nil.  If someone else did it, they would be making illegal use of illegally acquired code.

However, there are apparently some "[somewhat VB compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067894/visual-basic-in-linux)" languages available for linux and those may be in the pi distros.